# R - Values from 2D table

Tags: r, plyr

I want to pick values from a 2-D table and the (made-up) data I have is:

```
dat <- matrix(runif(50),nrow=10)
rownames(dat) <- 10:1
colnames(dat) <- 1:5
dat
```

2D table is:

> dat

```
        1         2          3          4          5
10 0.93428302 0.2637368 0.91326265 0.20931505 0.25215862
9  0.01458229 0.1401547 0.25761699 0.08444877 0.04543594
8  0.98966030 0.4418174 0.78787133 0.36977319 0.85497134
7  0.54360750 0.4014348 0.48607126 0.08431677 0.95499422
6  0.39402458 0.6774917 0.07525122 0.80501739 0.34954356
5  0.74283503 0.6652231 0.45576364 0.52726500 0.49623084
4  0.44952924 0.7003085 0.98825235 0.46539233 0.23546417
3  0.32351304 0.5867900 0.65499386 0.53018068 0.45590061
2  0.63876290 0.5140422 0.79265134 0.63175354 0.28500796
1  0.01185476 0.1773445 0.55828598 0.43911265 0.18718190
```

My other set:

```
xx <- sample(1:10,10,replace=FALSE)
yy <- sample(1:5,10,replace=TRUE)
zz <- 10:1
n.dat <- cbind(xx,yy,zz)
n.dat <- as.data.frame(n.dat)
```

And the dataset looks like:

```
   xx yy zz
1   5  3 10
2  10  4  9
3   1  3  8
4   8  5  7
5   7  2  6
6   6  1  5
7   2  4  4
8   9  2  3
9   3  5  2
10  4  1  1
```

I want to read values from the 1st table that correspond to "xx" and "yy" and save in an order as "zz" is defined.

What I tried:

```
library(plyr)
val <- daply(subset(n.dat,xx %in% n.dat$xx),"c",
                   function(x) {
                     d1=x$xx
                     d2=x$yy
                     res_tab_R["d1","d2"]           
                   } )
```

But instead of getting what I want, I get an error.

Values I want are:

```
   10       9     ....
  0.4558  0.2093  and so on.
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Using your `dat` and `n.dat`, I opted to start with a simple `apply`:

```
options(digits = 4)
apply(n.dat, 1, function(rr) dat[rr[1], rr[2]])
##        1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9      10 
##  0.07525 0.43911 0.91326 0.45590 0.70031 0.74284 0.08445 0.51404 0.85497 0.54361
```

However, I think you might be intending the `$xx` column to be referencing the row names not the row numbers (who uses numbers as row names *out of order*?). Note that `dat[1,]` references the top row, as does `dat['10',]` (notice the number/string difference). As such:

```
apply(n.dat, 1, function(rr) dat[as.character(rr[1]), rr[2]])
##       1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10 
##  0.4558 0.2093 0.5583 0.8550 0.4014 0.3940 0.6318 0.1402 0.4559 0.4495
```

This looks like what you listed after "Values I want are," but now I wonder what the `$zz` column is supposed to do, since indexing this further does not produce the output you said you wanted:

```
apply(n.dat, 1, function(rr) dat[rr[1], rr[2]])[n.dat$zz]
##       10       9       8       7       6       5       4       3       2       1 
##  0.54361 0.85497 0.51404 0.08445 0.74284 0.70031 0.45590 0.91326 0.43911 0.07525 
apply(n.dat, 1, function(rr) dat[as.character(rr[1]), rr[2]])[n.dat$zz]
##      10      9      8      7      6      5      4      3      2      1 
##  0.4495 0.4559 0.1402 0.6318 0.3940 0.4014 0.8550 0.5583 0.2093 0.4558
```

Perhaps out of this you can glean the answer you were requesting.

(BTW #1: You have two assignments to the same variable, so your `cbind()` call is being overwritten and ignored. It is unnecessary here.)

(BTW #2: You did a good job making a reproducible example, thank you. For completeness, it's customary to include `library(plyr)` (for `daply`) whenever you are deviating from the base packages of R. And, since sometimes people don't copy/paste consistently, many people also add `set.seed(1)` (or some integer) in the beginning whenever using random number generators. It's sometimes useful to see how the data structures were formed as well as what you did with them. Thoughts.)

Answer (score 0):

This would be a lot faster:

```
dat[ with(n.dat, cbind(xx,yy) )]
 [1] 0.07525122 0.43911265 0.91326265 0.45590061 0.70030850 0.74283503 0.08444877 0.51404220 0.85497134
[10] 0.54360750
```

(As pointed out, you may not be describing the problem very well. If I assign rownames to the matrix I can match on those and do the cbind strategy in an efficient oneliner:

```
 rownames(dat) <- 10:1
 dat[ with(n.dat, cbind(match(xx,rownames(dat)),yy) )]
 [1] 0.4557636 0.2093151 0.5582860 0.8549713 0.4014348 0.3940246 0.6317535 0.1401547 0.4559006 0.4495292
```

This is how you *should* post  examples (with output from `dput`:

```
dat <-
structure(c(0.93428302, 0.01458229, 0.9896603, 0.5436075, 0.39402458, 
0.74283503, 0.44952924, 0.32351304, 0.6387629, 0.01185476, 0.2637368, 
0.1401547, 0.4418174, 0.4014348, 0.6774917, 0.6652231, 0.7003085, 
0.58679, 0.5140422, 0.1773445, 0.91326265, 0.25761699, 0.78787133, 
0.48607126, 0.07525122, 0.45576364, 0.98825235, 0.65499386, 0.79265134, 
0.55828598, 0.20931505, 0.08444877, 0.36977319, 0.08431677, 0.80501739, 
0.527265, 0.46539233, 0.53018068, 0.63175354, 0.43911265, 0.25215862, 
0.04543594, 0.85497134, 0.95499422, 0.34954356, 0.49623084, 0.23546417, 
0.45590061, 0.28500796, 0.1871819), .Dim = c(10L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("10", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1"), NULL))

n.dat <- 
structure(list(xx = c(5L, 10L, 1L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 9L, 3L, 4L
), yy = c(3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 1L), zz = c(10L, 
9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L)), .Names = c("xx", "yy", 
"zz"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: I realized I didn't specify the problem very clearly. Anyways, if the column names are different then I think I can replace "xx" and "yy" with the specific column names. What if I need "zz" values on top of the answers too? For instance,

    10          9
   0.45576      0.2093

Comment: Do you mean to ask what to do if you want to match the colnames of dat to 'yy'? If so, I would think the answer is fairly obvious from the example of how to do it with the rownames.

Comment: No. The order w.r.t. zz. Like I want to have values of zz on top of the values obtained from the table.

Comment: I fear I'm too concrete. I'm going to need an example,

Comment: Nice, @BondedDust, I keep forgetting about indexing with matrices.